# Python - Tkinter Entry showing on the wrong window

Tags: python, tkinter, window, tkinter-entry

When the entry widget loads inside of the testing window, the new window loads however the widget loads in the first window. Any idea what I could change here.

```
import tkinter as tk

class programLauncher(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.TESTING_btn = tk.Button(self, text = "TESTING", command = self.varTesting)
        self.TESTING_btn.pack(side = "right", expand=True)

    def varTesting(self):
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("TESTING - Variables")
        warning = tk.Label(t, text = "WARNING TESTING ONLY")
        warning.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        sysCap = tk.Label(t, text = "System Cap")
        sysCap.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        sysCapInp = tk.Entry(bd = 5)
        sysCapInp.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = programLauncher(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a parent to the `Entry` widget, so it is added to the root window.

Answer (score 0):

```
    sysCapInp = tk.Entry(Parent, bd = 5)
    sysCapInp.pack()
```

i would also name it as self.sysCapInp so you can call sysCapInp .get() from elsewhere if needed instead of inside your one function

Comment: Running this gives a Syntax error because of the "<".